吉里吉里Zで System.inputString が使えない
FlashDevelopでtjs言語を使い、入力した文字を読み込もうと思いましたが、このようなエラーが出たときの対処を教えて下さい。
エラー文:
スクリプトで例外が発生しました
メンバ"inputString"が見つかりません

Javaで言う Scanner みたいなことがしたいです。
環境変数とかが原因なのでしょうか？
FlashDevelopを入れ直しても認識してくれませんでした。
ChatGPTに聞いたところ
window.prompt("",""), input(""), Args.join(" "), System.stdin.readLine()
これらを出されましたが、使えませんでした。
ネット上で探しても、どのサイトでも標準メソッドらしく、System.inputString("", "", ""); で動いています。
下記コード中のコメント部は https://github.com/mryp/kkefz の v1.0.0FD有り版 をダウンロードし、新規プロジェクトをKrkrZ Kag Projectで開始した際に自動でついてきたものです。
それ以下のコードについては http://tjs2.info/ を参照して書いていき、「1.5入力を受け取る（その１）」のところで詰まりました。
ソースコード:
/*

// startup.tjs - スタートアップスクリプト
// Copyright (C) 2001, W.Dee  改変・配布は自由です

@if (kirikiriz)
property _dummyProp { getter {} setter (v) {} }
with(Window) {
    &.innerSunken    = &_dummyProp;
    &.showScrollBars = &_dummyProp;
}

Plugins.link("menu.dll");
Plugins.link("KAGParser.dll");
@endif

// このスクリプトは一番最初に実行されるスクリプトです
Scripts.execStorage("system/Initialize.tjs"); // system/Initialize.tjs を実行

*/

System.inform("TJS");
var d = new Date();
System.inform(d.getHours()+"時"+d.getMinutes()+"分");

var message=System.inputString("inputStringメソッドのテスト", "数字を入力してください。", "");
System.inform(Message,"入力された値");


詳しくありませんが、参考まで。
「吉里吉里2」には有ったらしい System.inputString は「吉里吉里Z」で削除されたようです（フォントによっては混同するかも知れませんが、「2」と「Z」です）。

1行入力ダイアログ(System.inputString)
吉里吉里Zリポジトリに同梱されている Krkr2Compat を読み込むと利用可能
—— 『吉里吉里Zで削除された機能』より

公式サイトのAPIリファレンスなども参考になるでしょう。
